# "Not enough free space to perform encryption" although there is free space on the disk

Tags: encryption, disk-usage

[image]

I'm getting an error in my Ubuntu, saying that there's not enough free space to perform encryption, even though I have it (I freed up 80GB).

Anyone had a similar problem and have a solution?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What encryption are you trying to use? What are the exact steps or commands you have used. Can you cut and past the error into the question? You need to give some details.

Comment: ecrypt-utils encryption. I used the instruction listed on jumpcloud with below link https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-encrypt-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-post-installation

Comment: You still need to give the version of Ubuntu.

Comment: sorry i am using ubuntu 22.04

Comment: How much data are you encrypting? You’ll need at least 25% above the target amount for the first pass …

Comment: i just added the image of the disk. Is way more than that

Comment: @David any idea